# Similar matrices represent an operator relative to different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove the following

> Let $A,C$ be two similar matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}$.
>
> Define $T_A : \mathbb{F}^n_{\text{col}} \to \mathbb{F}^n_{\text{col}}$ as $T_A(x) = Ax$.
>
> Prove that there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{F}^n_{\text{col}}$ such that $[T_A]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}} = C$. That is, the representation of $T_A$ relative to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is $C$.

I couldn't really figure any significant leads, but my first few steps:

The representation of $T_A$ relative to the standard basis, call it $\mathcal{\varepsilon}$, is simply $A$.

$A\sim C \Rightarrow A = PCP^{-1}$

I think maybe I should prove that since $A\sim C$ then the invertible P is the change of basis matrix, but I can't seem to prove that.

Another attempt:
$
T_A(Pe_1) = APe_1 = PCe_1
$ 
But still nothing came up.

Any leads or ways to think of this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a small correction: In Line 3 it should be $A \sim C$ and not $A \sim B$. Now to the "real" problem:

I'll give you a hint and if that does not lead you anywhere, just leave a comment and I will state a complete answer.

Let us use your own notation and say that $\varepsilon = \{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n_{col}$. As you stated correctly the representation of $T_A$ in $\varepsilon$ is just $A$. But that means that there is some linear mapping $T_P$ with representation $P$ in $\varepsilon$. Now what does that mean? What happens when you throw all the basis vectors $e_i$ into $P$? Has the set $\{Pe_1, \ldots, Pe_n\}$ a "special" meaning for $\mathbb{F}^n_{col}$ if you know that $P$ is invertible?

From what you've written yourself, I think you can answer these questions and get to the complete answer yourself. If you're stuck somewhere, let me know in the comments!

Comment: First of all, thank you. Second, I concluded from your suggestions that ${Pe_1,\ldots,Pe_n}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n_{col}$. Another conclusion is that $T_A(Pe_i) = APe_i = PCe_i = PC_i$ where $C_i$ is the $i$-th column of $C$. I think I am missing something regarding matrix representations. If you could give me another clue so I can focus my attention to the correct idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: I figured it out, thank you!